# Some general question about bakery algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, operating-system

In this bakery algorithm, choosing[n] is initialized to False, And number[n] Also 0

```
int number[n];
bool choosing[n];
while(1){
  choosing[i] = True;
  number[i] = 1 + max(number[0] + ..... + number[n-1]);
  choosing[i] = False;
  for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++){
    while(choosing[j]);
    while(number[j]!=0 && ((number[j],j)<(number[i],i)));
  }
  // Critical Section
  number[i] = 0;
}
```

In this code 
If "choosing[i] = TRUE and choosing[i] = FALSE, while(choosing[i]);" is removed, can we keep mutual exclusion?

However, number[i] is either assigned a value or not assigned.

Comment: Where is `i` initialised? What does it signify?

Comment: variable i means pid, And this algorithm is bakery algorithm

Comment: [Lamport's bakery algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) doesn't work on modern processors. To quote the article: *"Lamport's bakery algorithm assumes a sequential consistency memory model. Few, if any, languages or multi-core processors implement such a memory model. Therefore correct implementation of the algorithm typically requires inserting fences to inhibit reordering."*

Comment: Good info, but I wonder if this can violate the mutual exclusion rule.